# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed collecting certificates for

Tags: android, flutter

I have this error.

```
adb: failed to install ok.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed collecting certificates for /data/app/vmdl1260875114.tmp/base.apk: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1260875114.tmp/base.apk: META-INF/TAPANDTU.SF indicates /data/app/vmdl1260875114.tmp/base.apk is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2, but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?]
```

What I have done is,

```
$fvm flutter build apk --release

$zip -d ./build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk 'META-INF/*'

$apksigner sign --ks tapandtunes.keystore --v1-signing-enabled true --v2-signing-enabled true ./build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk

$apksigner verify -v ./build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk

Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): true
Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4): false
Verified for SourceStamp: false
Number of signers: 1
```

then zip align

```
zipalign -f -p -v 4 ./build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk ok.apk
```

Everythin looks working fine,

but I have the error above when using this command.

```
`adb install ok.apk`
```

Comment: Same error here, do you resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Review this part got to `android/app/build.gradle` this file and review this part

```
android{
  ...
   buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I googled with the keyword you gave, found the article here. https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android